# Q: PySpark, how to iterate over rows in a large datafram?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a large data frame containing at least half a million records, I need to convert each string to a custom object(should end up with a list of objects)
collect () is not acceptable because the data frame is too large.

There was a problem with iterating over all the rows in the data frame, at first I tried to do it like this (led to a map, and a map to a list of objects):

```
result_list = map(Lambda row: row, test_df.collect())
```

But collect () turned out to be unacceptable because the dataframe is too big.

Could you please tell me what other options are there to iterate over each row in the dataframe?

Comment: Have you tried creating a UDF?

Comment: @VladSiv no, I may have a misunderstanding, but I don’t know how to solve this problem with udf, is it possible to write udf that will help convert dataframe to list or map?
(even if I do all the rows transformations in the dataframe itself, there is still the problem of putting it in the list of objects that is required at the output of the program)

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood the problem then. I thought you can just work with a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If collect() for your DataFrame doesn't fit into memory, it's unlikely your transformed DataFrame would fit either. However, if you just need to stream over your DataFrame and process each row one at a time, you could use `test_df.rdd.toLocalIterator()` to iterate over it. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.toLocalIterator.html